# Enable javascript in IE11 for local content ( file )

Tags: javascript

A simple script to test javascript

```
<!DOCTYPE html>

<meta charset="utf-8">
<title>Minimal Example</title>

<h1 id="header">This is JavaScript</h1>

<script>
    document.body.appendChild(document.createTextNode('Hello World!'));

    var h1 = document.getElementById('header'); // holds a reference to the <h1> tag
    h1 = document.getElementsByTagName('h1')[0]; // accessing the same <h1> element
</script>

<noscript>Your browser either does not support JavaScript, or has it turned off.</noscript>
```

Works fine in chrome.

Not so in IE11, even though I have scripts enabled

[image]

What do I need to do?

( It is IE11

[image]

Comment: that does not look like IE11, but I could be wrong.

Comment: Your document has no `<body>`, which might throw any browser off (though it shouldn't in HTML5 iirc)

Comment: @DLeh, you're not wrong at all.

Comment: Added body made no difference

Comment: Screenshot added to show running IE11

Comment: @ravenspoint dont just add body, make a proper html structure, test it in w3c validator if you wish. before trying to figure out whats wrong, make your document look like a proper html document and not like doodles in notepad.

Comment: Local files wouldn't be considered part of the "Internet" zone (i.e. from an apparently remote server). Check the settings under the other zones, especially "Intranet."

Comment: I would appreciate it if someone posted a "proper html document" that tests javascript in both chrome and IE11

Comment: @ravenspoint, your first screenshot is definitely not IE11. Your second is, but it looks like it does not come from the same machine (the font used for UI elements is visibly not the same). Maybe you have your VMs mixed up?

Comment: @FrédéricHamidi It can be IE11, with the "Windows Basic" theme being active.

Comment: @Jonathan, and the About box in general and its Close button in particular would be using a different, more "modern" font? Color me skeptic.

Comment: Try to close your browser and reopen after change your settings. It may work.

Comment: I rebooted after changing settings

Comment: Please write valid HTML with html and body tags. Validate your HMTL.

Comment: You really need to fix that HTML

Comment: I find both screenshot have the same theme. Probably window basic which makes it look like not IE11

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Found the answer in [this link](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/ieinternals/archive/2011/03/23/understanding-local-machine-zone-lockdown-restricted-this-webpage-from-running-scripts-or-activex-controls.aspx) provided by NoGray

[image]

Answer (score 1):

When you run IE on your desktop, scripts are considered blocked content until the user allow them. On the bottom of your browser, you should have a yellow bar that asks you to "Allow Blocked Content". Click on that to run the script.

Comment: This sounds correct.  How can I change this behaviour?

Comment: You can read about possible solutions here http://blogs.msdn.com/b/ieinternals/archive/2012/06/20/loading-local-files-in-enhanced-protected-mode-in-internet-explorer-10.aspx The easiest option is to add comments like <!-- saved from url=(0022)http://127.0.0.1:8088/ --> under the doctype (you will need to restart IE to see it work)